# What is SQL Server statement to get day and month ignoring the current year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `HD_Case_Master` with a column `cm_date_created`.

The example value is `2011-05-13 10:07:36.000`.

I manage to get the current year but how to get record for all day and month.

SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    cm_create_date 
FROM 
    HD_Case_Master 
WHERE
    YEAR(cm_create_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND ???
```

Comment: Do you want to check if `cm_date_created` is equal to the current date, ignoring the time component?

Comment: What do you mean "all day and month"?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exact your problem is ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current date:

```
SELECT cm_create_date
FROM HD_Case_Master 
WHERE cm_create_date >= CAST(GETDATE() as date) AND
      cm_create_date < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE()) as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if `cm_date_created` is equal to the current date, ignoring the time component, you just need to `CAST` both dates to `DATE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM HD_Case_Master
WHERE
    CAST(cm_create_date AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Alternatively, you can use `>=` and `<` to check if `cm_date_created` falls within the current date:

```
SELECT *
FROM HD_Case_Master
WHERE
    cm_create_date >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND cm_create_date < CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Comment: You should point out the second is typically faster because the server can use indexes on the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEPART function of tsql.

```
... Where DATEPART(day, cm_create_date) = DATEPART(day, getdate()) AND DATEPART(month, cm_create_date) = DATEPART(month, getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

You were really close! To add just the month (but ignoring the year), just use this:

```
SELECT 
    cm_create_date 
FROM 
    HD_Case_Master 
WHERE
    YEAR(cm_create_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(cm_create_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```